# setstate object:{array:[]} in reactjs how could i add the **key and value inside the array which is in the state object**?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

> > key and value inside the array which is in the state object
>
> this.state = {
>    frequency: { 
>   days: [], 
>   startdate: "", 
>   customdate: "" },
>      };

how could i add the key ad value inside the days array?

Comment: Hello and welcome. You have to update your question, it is not clear what is your problem and therefore hard to answer properly. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function addKeyValue(key, value) {

  this.setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    frequency: {
       ...state.frequency,
       days: [...state.frequency.days, {[key]: value}]
    }
  })
}
```

--Edit

Removing the key is a bit trickier.

```js
function removeKeyValue(key, value) {

  this.setState(state => {
    const days = state.frequency.days;
    const dayIndex = days.findIndex(pr => pr[key] === value);
    const day = {...days[dayIndex]};
    delete day[key];

    return {
      ...state,
      frequency: {
         ...state.frequency,
         days: [...days.slice(0, dayIndex),
            day,
            ...days.slice(dayIndex + 1)]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: tanks a lot and how could i remove the key and value ..?

Comment: Updated answer. If you wan't to remove key in item in a specific index you have to change function a bit

Comment: actually its not working... i'm using the array to add only the value as requirement..    this.setState(
        (state) => ({
          ...state,
          frequency: {
            ...state.frequency,
            days: [...state.frequency.days, parseInt(val)],
          },
        }),
        () => {
          console.log(this.state.frequency.days);
        }
      );

Comment: Then what do you use `key` for?

Comment: as per new requirement i don't need key juz

Comment: Jozef can you get me solution please

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your state by using `setState` like this:

```
this.setState({frequency: {...this.state.frequency, days: [...this.state.frequency.days, day]}});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.